# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Articles#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Following is the code where error is shown.

```
<%= form_for :article, url: article_path(@article), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

What is this error,whenever I click edit from previous screen , I think I am sending the article id.

Here is my rake routes output

```
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

Comment: Can you post your `rake routes` output?

Comment: I have included rake routes output in the question itself now

Comment: What happens when you change that line to `<%= form_for @article, url: article_path(@article), method: :patch do |f| %>` ?

Comment: This bug is generated when i was following the walk through process to use Ruby and rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html . Possibly the document needs to be updated ? This is confusing. Any one with correct solution yet please help.

Comment: Turns out i was missing the edit function.
`def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end`

If anyone got the same error. Please dont forget to add the edit method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your question

```
<%= form_for :article, url: article_path(@article), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

Check your url: article_path(@article) this is the path helper for your article show action and if you check your rake routes it says for show action you need a `get` request but you are using a `patch` method or if you are trying to edit an article then your path helper is wrong and hence **no route error**

**Fix**

**To show an article:**

*If you want to show an article then instead of a form_for use link_to which by default use a get request*, **form_for is used to create an article and not for showing an article**

```
<%= link_to "Article", articles_path(@article) %>
```

**To create or edit an article:**

a. **Using polymorphic urls**

*If you want to create an article or edit an article then you can use **rails polymorphic urls** and don't need to specify url option, rails will handle this internally. So for creating and editing an article you can use the same form*

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  // your fields
<% end %>
```

For this to work you need to have this in your controller

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

b. **Using path_helpers**

If you'll hardcode url option in your form then it'll take you to that action only and hence you'll require separate forms

For creating:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: article_path do |f| %>
  // your fields
<% end %>
```

For editing:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: article_path(@article) do |f| %>
  // your fields
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm having this exact problem and trying both the polymorphic urls and path_helpers for editing an article didn't help. The same error arises with path_helpers and an ArgumentError arises with polymorphic urls. This material comes from [this rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-articles). I'm not sure the Stack Overflow best practices are for reviving a old problem but I thought I'd leave a comment before making a new post.

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot and didn't notice the code with ```def edit...``` which is what I was missing. Ignore the comment above.

Comment: @user1489726 no issues. Glad to hear that you got it working :)